# Show: (A ∪ B) × C = (A × C) ∪ (B × C).

Tags: discrete-mathematics

We are on splitting cases and this problem has me stumped. I know it's not that hard but I've tried so many different ways to solve it and nothing seems correct to me.

Answer (score 2):

$\underline{(A\cup B)\times C \subseteq (A\times C)\cup (B\times C)}$: Let $\mathbf{x}\in (A\cup B)\times C$, so $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2)$ where $x_1\in (A\cup B)$ and $x_2\in C$. It follows that $x_1\in A$ or $x_1\in B$ (by definition of set union), and $x_2\in C$. But then we have $(x_1, x_2)\in A\times C$ or $(x_1, x_2)\in B\times C$, so $(x_1, x_2)\in (A\times C)\cup (B\times C)$. Therefore $\mathbf{x}\in (A\times C)\cup (B\times C)$, and we can conclude that
$$
(A\cup B)\times C \subseteq (A\times C)\cup (B\times C).
$$

Try proving $(A\times C)\cup (B\times C) \subseteq (A\cup B)\times C$ by following what I wrote above as a guide.